# What are the names of the Summer Getaway Badge levels on Steam?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

After crafting the Summer Getaway Badge I noticed that it had multiple levels. What are the names of the various levels?

Comment: It's the same as every other badge out there, so I don't understand what's the point of this question.  All normal cards can be crafted up to Level 5, and Foils can be crafted up to Level 1.

Comment: Retrosaur, the question isn't about the number of levels. It is a question of the names. Still, thanks for the info on the foils, that was a little obscure to me.

Comment: Your first edit was a little ambiguous, but your edit actually made it a lot clearer. I posted that comment because the question was so vague 'what are the levels for the badge?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Steam Sightseer
2. Digital Day-Tripper
3. Virtual Voyager
4. Joystick Jester
5. Vacation Veteran

I have first hand confirmation of levels 1 through 5. According members in the Steam forums there exist a Foil badge, Gaming Globetrotter. I have yet to confirm its existence as I have no foil badges.